# PHP - Convert xy .shp coordinates to Google Maps lat/lng

Tags: php, google-maps, coordinates, shapefile

I am developing a web application in which it is possible to load an .shp file. The idea is to recognize this file and then display each polygon in a Google Maps. I can read the shape file in php. The problem is i do not know how to convert the coordinate system used in .shp to the coordinate system that recognizes Google Maps for map manipulation. These are some of the coordinates of the .shp file and the coordinate system used in that file:

Coordinates system (.prj file):

```
LOCAL_CS["CH1903+ / LV95",UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
```

Interpreted .shp records:

```
Record number: 1
Array
(
    [bounding_box] => Array
        (
            [xmin] => 2645165.87317
            [xmax] => 2645166.87317
            [ymin] => 1132483.62903
            [ymax] => 1132484.62903
        )

    [numparts] => 1
    [parts] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [numrings] => 1
                [rings] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [numpoints] => 5
                                [points] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [x] => 2645165.87317
                                                [y] => 1132484.62903
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [x] => 2645166.87317
                                                [y] => 1132484.62903
                                            )

                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [x] => 2645166.87317
                                                [y] => 1132483.62903
                                            )

                                        [3] => Array
                                            (
                                                [x] => 2645165.87317
                                                [y] => 1132483.62903
                                            )

                                        [4] => Array
                                            (
                                                [x] => 2645165.87317
                                                [y] => 1132484.62903
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[wkt] => POLYGON((2645165.87317 1132484.62903, 2645166.87317 1132484.62903, 2645166.87317 1132483.62903, 2645165.87317 1132483.62903, 2645165.87317 1132484.62903)))
Array
(
    [_deleted] => 
    [ID] => 1
    [red] => 58.818
    [Comment] => 
    [Rate] => 0.000
)

Record 2 [...]
```

Note: For reading .shp file i use gasparesganga/php-shapefile library, https://github.com/gasparesganga/php-shapefile

Comment: The term you are looking for is probably "reproject", I'm not sure what tools there are in PHP. You need to reproject from the Swiss coordinate system ([EPSG:2056](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2056/)?) to projected WGS84 coordinates [EPSG:3857](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7483/), see also [this GIS SE question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the library Proj4php https://github.com/proj4php/proj4php to reproject your coordinates.

```
$proj4 = new Proj4php();

// Your initial projection information from your .prj file
$srcProj    = new Proj('LOCAL_CS["CH1903+ / LV95",UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]', $proj4);

// WGS84 (for google map)
$dstProj  = new Proj('EPSG:4326', $proj4);

// Your original point
$srcPoint = new Point(2645165.87317, 1132484.62903, $srcProj);

// Create your new point in WGS84 projection
$dstPoint = $proj4->transform($dstProj, $srcPoint);
```